# Magento not access to shop or admin panel

Tags: magento

since I changed the web URL in the admin panel from www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/magento.
I dont have access to the shop or the admin panel.

Do you know how I could correct this mistake?

Cheers,

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

What do you exactly mean with "correcting the mistake"?

If you mean changing the url back, you could login to the database and change the secure/unsecure base_url in the core_config_data table